# Execute a Dart function in background when the flutter app Autostart's on BOOT_COMPLETED?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dart, flutter

In my Flutter app rather than loading the entire app on the screen, I wish to execute a small Dart function in the background as soon as the app receives the Autostart on BOOT_COMPLETED message.

The app should load normally when the user launches it from the launcher, however when the app receives the Autostart on BOOT_COMPLETED message it should just run a small dart function in the background without the app actually loading on the screen.

So far I have used the code from the following git >> https://github.com/oatpano/flutter_boot_startup

However this code will run the entire app on the screen.

I am not a Android developer, so I'm having issues figuring what is exactly going on in the manifest file.

So in the following example I would like to execute the backgroundfunction() only when the app receives the Autostart on BOOT_COMPLETED message

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
   runApp(new MyApp());
}

void backgroundfunction(){
    print("Hello world");
}
```

Comment: As far as i understand that repository, it's sole purpose is to launch the activity on startup. So what you are seeing is pretty much expected. Why exactly do you want to execute code after boot up? If you want to run code every few minutes, maybe background_fetch plugin could be useful: https://github.com/transistorsoft/flutter_background_fetch it has a similar feature which allows headless mode: https://github.com/transistorsoft/flutter_background_fetch/blob/master/help/INSTALL-ANDROID.md#headless-mechanism-with-enableheadless-true

Comment: @herbert thanks for your time. I can run the code periodically in background with flutter_background_fetch. The package is awesome and it will execute the function even if the app is terminated by the user and no longer in the memory. However if the user reboots the device the periodic background execution stops. I could have used flutter_background_fetch if it were to execute the function even after a boot.

Comment: it does, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [background_fetch plugin](https://github.com/transistorsoft/flutter_background_fetch) and make sure:

1. You follow the [headless mode documentation](https://github.com/transistorsoft/flutter_background_fetch/blob/master/help/INSTALL-ANDROID.md#headless-mechanism-with-enableheadless-true)
2. Enable `startOnBoot: true` by [during configuration of the service](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/background_fetch/latest/background_fetch/BackgroundFetchConfig/startOnBoot.html) which will either [use a BOOT_COMPLETED receiver](https://github.com/transistorsoft/transistor-background-fetch/blob/3bfd68ead67e221b680d55c0c5b3264d136b04a6/android/tsbackgroundfetch/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L9-L13) on Android < 21, or a [persisted JobService](https://github.com/transistorsoft/transistor-background-fetch/blob/3bfd68ead67e221b680d55c0c5b3264d136b04a6/android/tsbackgroundfetch/src/main/java/com/transistorsoft/tsbackgroundfetch/BackgroundFetch.java#L84-L88) on Android >= 21